# d3v4 - 'transition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code that draw `rect` at position based on the data provided:

```
var self = this;
var targetrect = d3.select(this.$el).select('svg').selectAll('g')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {return d.pricepos - 5;})
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {return (i+1) *itemh - itemh/2 -5;})
    .attr('width','10')
    .attr('height','10')
    .attr('fill', '#000000');
```

Then, I want to animate it moving to target position after a `timeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
        self.targetrect
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {return d.pricetargetpos - 5;});
}, 500);
```

but I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transition' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you assign `targetrect` to `this`/`self`? You've either missed that part or left it out from the question.

Comment: @Svenskunganka Based on your comment, I just take out the `self` and it works. Can you put your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. A small tip is to use ES2015 arrow functions to preserve scope to `this` so you don't have to do `var self = this` again.

Comment: I am using `vue.js`, for some reason that is required if you want to use function within functions. I don't understand well enough to explain it.

Comment: ES2015 (also known as ES6) is a new version of JavaScript with added features, which you can read more about [here](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis). You're writing "old" ES5 code, which still works and has better backwards-compatibility, but has quite some quirks like `this` going out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't assigned `targetrect` to `this`. Changing this line:

```
var targetrect = d3.select(this.$el).select('svg').selectAll('g')
```

to

```
self.targetrect = d3.select(this.$el).select('svg').selectAll('g')
```

If the `setTimeout` function is in the same scope as the scope where you assign `targetrect`, you can completely omit `self` from inside the setTimeout callback, like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
        targetrect
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr('x', function(d, i) {return d.pricetargetpos - 5;});
}, 500);
```